# Cómo puedo editar un campo tipo IMAGE, deseo dejar el registro en NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la tabla pacientes la cual tiene un campo llamado `FOTO` tipo `IMAGE`. Hay algunos registros que deseo editar y ya no me sirve tener la imagen que me aparece guardada allí. Entonces me gustaria saber de qué forma puedo eliminar esa foto de forma general en todos mis pacientes y así mantener el Campo `FOTO` para tenerlo a la mano por si lo necesito en un futuro, pero que todos los registros que tengan asociado una imagen solo actualize y me borre dicha imagen de la tabla `pacientes` que tengo.

Intenté hacerlo con:

```
USE [Pruebas]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Pacientes] SET [Foto] = NULL WHERE FOTO <> NULL
GO
```

Pero esto resultó en el error siguiente:

> Mens. 306, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1 No se pueden comparar ni ordenar los tipos de datos text, ntext e image, excepto cuando se utiliza el operador IS NULL o LIKE.

Comment: ¿Has probado armar una sentencia `UPDATE`?

Comment: si, solo que no se el dato exacto o como armar la sentencia porque el tipo imagen no se deja comparar con cadenas de texto y tampoco se deja comparar con signos me arroja error en ese momento

Comment: Por favor comparte el SQL que intentastes y el error que te da.

Comment: Mens. 306, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
No se pueden comparar ni ordenar los tipos de datos text, ntext e image, excepto cuando se utiliza el operador IS NULL o LIKE.


USE [Pruebas]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Pacientes]
   SET 
      [Foto] =  NULL
 WHERE FOTO <> NULL
GO

Comment: En vez de `FOTO <> NULL`, usa `FOTO IS NULL`. O si quieres, omite la condición y solo haz, `UPDATE pacientes SET Foto = null`.

Comment: Funciono bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por si acaso, te aviso que me equivoqué. Quise decir `IS NOT NULL`, en vez de `IS NULL`. Disculpa.

Comment: Por favor @DanielSoto si el comentario de sstan te ayudó, lo invito a que lo formule como respuesta, lo des por válido y cierres la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar los operadores `=` o `<>` no es legal con el tipo `IMAGE`. Y aunque lo fuera, usar esos operadores para verificar si un campo es `NULL` no te daría el resultado correcto. `NULL` es especial, y para verificar su presencia o ausencia, debes usar `IS NOT NULL` o `IS NULL`.

De modo que la consulta correcta en tu caso es:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Pacientes]
   SET [Foto] = NULL
 WHERE FOTO IS NOT NULL
```